# update version in package.json to be the same as project.version in POM

Tags: angularjs, maven

I am actually trying to do some automatisation on my project.

Actually I run a command to update my POM version usgin `mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=X.X.X-SNAPSHOT`.

I have to update the version in the package.json of my application manualy each time I do this.

How could I link the package version to my POM version?

I try sheacrhing some answer but could not find anything that does'nt require for me to rerun another command line

(Application achitectur : POM parent/POM Backend (java)/Pom FrontEnd (AngularJS))

Comment: I don't know of any way to link both versions, but you can write a script that updates both versions and just use this script instead of the above command.

Comment: the point is to not use another script to do so but to manage to link both together to win time when i upgrade the versions of my projects

Comment: What is the package.json file within a Maven project for? Sounds like Angular ?

Comment: it is the package.json file from agularJS (Java Backend with maven and AngularJS for our Frontend managed by maven)

Comment: Is the AngularJS within the same project as the Backend part?

Comment: it is under the same parent POM but the backend and the frontend have their onw POM to link them to the POM Parent

Answer (score 6):

`npm version 'your version'` updates the package.json to the specified version.

`npm version patch|minor|major` auto increments your version.

Add this command to your pom.xml and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hiho,

even though it's been quite some time since you asked.... maybe this Maven plugin will help you. :)

https://github.com/ingogriebsch/sync-packagejson-version-maven-plugin